# Displaying selected JRadioButton value in JTextField

Tags: java, click, jtextfield, jradiobutton

The following java code part is used by me to get the string value of the selected radio button(There are 4 radio buttons with names Add,Sub, Mul and Div)(The button group is buttonGroup1 )

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(evt.getSource()==buttonGroup1){
        value=buttonGroup1.getSelectedItem().getActionCommand();
        switch(value){

            case("Add"):
                jTextField3.setText("Add the number");
                break;

            case("Sub"):
                jTextField3.setText("Substract");
                break; 

             case("Div"):
                jTextField3.setText("Multiply");
                break;

             case("Mul"):
                jTextField3.setText("Divide");
                break;

        }



    }

} 


   private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;

    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton3;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
```

"value" is a string variable!I want to display the radio button values in JTextField3 when JButton1 is clicked! My program does not give any compile errors but neither works! how can i correct this issue?

Comment: I don't see any radio buttons in this code.

Comment: now you see bro :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the [how to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then provide us with a [mcve].